# Monkeypatch Javascript constructor

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, monkeypatching, zip.js

I've read all of the other related answers I've been able to find, but none has worked. Essentially, I want to make this source:
https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/zip.js/blob/master/WebContent/zip-ext.js

add some custom headers to `the XMLHttpRequest` on line 93. Since `HTTPRangeReader` is wrapped in an anonymous function, I can't monkeypatch it directly, and it seems the only option is to monkeypatch the `XMLHttpRequest` constructor. I just need to call the default constructor and then call `setRequestHeader()` one or more times before returning the new object.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias to clone the original then reference it in the method override:

```js
    function handler()
      {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
      }

    /* Avoid stack overflow */
    if (XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySetRequestHeader === undefined)
      { 
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySetRequestHeader = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader;
      }

    /* Override prototype method */
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.setRequestHeader = function baz(foo, bar)
      {
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySetRequestHeader.call(this, 'foo', 'bar');
      XMLHttpRequest.prototype.mySetRequestHeader.call(this, 'bar', 'baz');
      
      }

    /* Test the override */
    with (new XMLHttpRequest)
      {
      open('GET', location.href);
      setRequestHeader("referer","http://www.example.com");
      send("");
      onreadystatechange = handler;
      }
```

**References**

- [AJAX Interception](http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/06/10/ajax-interception/)
- [JavaScript Override Patterns](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/02/javascript-override-patterns.html)
- [XMLHttpRequest Specification: setRequestHeader](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader)
- [Capturing javascript console.log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/1113772)
- [ECMAScript Strawman: Subclassable Builtins](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:subclassable-builtins&do=export_raw)
- [Overriding external object's function using JavaScript in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641437/1113772)